# Which cloud storage service will be better for my needs?

Tags: storage

I'm using multiple Raspberry Pi devices. I use one for RPi software development (I'm programmer), one for multimedia (RaspBMC), and one for other purposes.

The way I'm moving files to these devices and manage them from PC is not productive.

I would like to use one of cloud storage services (Google Drive, Dropbox or maybe something else) to sync all devices with folders on my PC, so I can just put files in folder on PC and wait until these files will be synchronized with RPi.

I want to create directory structures like this (or similar):

**PC:**

```
RPi Devices
    RPi Multimedia
        home
            cloud-multimedia
            cloud-all

    RPi Dev    
        home
            cloud-dev
            cloud-all
        var
            www

    RPi Sandbox
        home
            cloud-sandbox
            cloud-all
        var
            www
```

**RPi devices:**

```
\home\myusername\cloud-multimedia             (only on "RPi Multimedia")
\home\myusername\cloud-dev                    (only on "RPi Dev")
\home\myusername\cloud-sandbox                (only on "RPi Sandbox")
\home\myusername\cloud-all                    (shared on all devices)
\var\www\                                     (separate for Dev and Sandbox devices)
```

Two of my RPi devices have Raspbian. One is RaspBMC.

I'm already using Google Drive and Dropbox services. If there is something else for my needs - I can give it a try). My question is:

**Which cloud service will be easier to configure for my needs and work on both - Raspbian and RaspBMC?**

I'm using Windows 7 on my PC and current versions of Raspbian and RaspBMC on Raspberry devices.

Comment: Thought of OwnCloud? I am using it and is really great. I sync the Pi, two laptops.

Comment: I never heard about OwnCloud. But it is not real cloud storage, I have to use server with public IP for this, right?

Comment: Get yourself a $10/month VPS and start using `git` via ssh!  And whatever else you want. Your cloud, your rules.

Comment: USe bittorrent synch. Version 2 is comming out and is going to be awesome. And like Goldilocks says, use a VPS, I do this with a 2TB mirrored one for about 20USD and 250mbps internet. Then I save files to my local servers and computers. Completly private. I dont trust any commercial cloud for sensitive data any more, especially dropflops. No need to setup proxies, VPN's or firewalls. Everything is encryppted on clients using the secret, computer permissions, people permission, sharing, passwords, webgui. Its already pretty awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use Dropbox, I think you should stick to it. It is really easy to set up on Linux if you follow [these](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) instructions. Also, the package may already be on the Rasbpian repo, so you should be able to easily install it with apt-get. Following that, [here](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli) you can find some easy instructions for the cli interface. Once you get everything sorted out, it is really easy to begin sharing files. In the shared folder you can make the directory tree that you like and continue from there. As for RasBMC, I think you can easily install from the command line with the full-manual process.